# Javascript Text Editor Basic Functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

I'm attempting to write my own WYSWG text editor in Javascript, but I'm struggling with what seems to be a rather basic problem.

Given a selection of text inside a contentEditable area such as what is between the pipes '|' here:

`<span class="italic">Some text that |I would want</span> to edit or| select`

I can figure out what I need to do here to essentially move the closing span tag so that my selection is included in the italic span. However, there are a plethora of other cases that I need to account for such as if I want to remove the span, add another span around an area that already contains an opening or closing span, account for opening/closing other tag types around my selection, etc.

Is there some library that exists anywhere that provides this selection/replace logic for me? Or am I asking too much? Would I be better off using one of the many editors already available on the web?

I would really like to not have to use the last option since most of the ones I've found seem extremely heavy weight since I really only want a few custom editing functions.

Comment: Why are you trying to re-invent the wheel?  http://www.tinymce.com/

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: @kennis: it's all how its loaded, you can load it barebone without all the extra stuff.  http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/multiple_configs.php

Comment: @ZeeTee Touché. That's a fair point.

Comment: Well I wanted to take this as a kind of learning experience. Also, tinyMCE is really gigantic when I need only a few of the functions it offers and I wanted to add a few functions that it does not offer. I figure if I can get this issue figured out, there won't be too much more difficulty.

Comment: @kennis I have an insert function that basically replaces the given selection with a <span> of the style I want to apply. I implemented something to check if there's another <span> with the same style inside that selection and delete it. However, the more of this I code, the more edge cases I realize there are.

Comment: Well, you can also add your own functionality i believe to tinyMce: http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/listbox_splitbutton.php

Comment: What do you actually want to do to the selected content?

Comment: basically just apply different styles to it, different formatting, etc. I am planning to do this through mostly <span> elements with different classes depending on the style I want. I might want to use other tags though such as <p> for formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Rangy and its modules
http://code.google.com/p/rangy/
http://code.google.com/p/rangy/#Modules

ContentEditable is a nasty beast with many quirks between browsers. Rangy tries to solve that but it's still difficult to work with. My project has a lot of custom rules so we had to use a lower level library like Rangy. Combined with jQuery it is very powerful.

Comment: I'll have to take a deeper look into it, but at first glance this looks like exactly what I need! Great, thanks!